# Looking for some good GUI testing frameworks/gui automation test tools for Windows Forms .NET

Tags: .net, user-interface, automation, testing

I am looking for a good **GUI** testing framework/automation testing tool for windows forms based apps.

Can you recommend any ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used [White](http://www.codeplex.com/white) in the past with some success. It also has a White.NUnit component which that allows you to integrate your tests into NUnit.

When I used it, it was relatively easy to investigate the UI, get hold of buttons, menus, etc.., click them, and then verify that the correct things happened - all from C#. Combined with NUnit asserts, it enables you to verify the UI behaves as you expect. I did have some problems with some types of controls not working properly. It has moved on a bit since I last used it so you may have more luck with the latest version.

Comment: We use only 3rd party controls for our winforms client/server app like devexpress/infragistics. 

Have you ever considered automatedQA ? http://www.automatedqa.com/

Often commercial products are more mature and we do not care spend some bucks...

From whitees site: 64 Bit Windows
White is currently not tested on 64-bit windows, so you might face issues with it.

:/ our dev machines are all win 7 64bit, I do not want to be another beta

 tester ;P

Comment: @msfanboy: Yes - our QA team use TestComplete to run the smoke tests. I've not used it personally, but the QA team demoed it to us and it looked quite good.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good experience with [AutomatedQA](http://automatedqa), although I've mainly used it for testing web apps rather than standalone Windows apps.  It's much better value than most of the other commercial tools and has a good feature set and choice of scripting languages.

Comment: automatedqa looks good but - I checked it but found nothing about it - can AutomatedQA also handle Acceptance/Story testing means changing/clicking in GUI and see the data hitting the backend?

I know "White" framework can do that at least they write it. From AutomatedQA I haven`t seen an announcement about that in their feature list.

Comment: Can AutomatedQA also analyse how much of the GUI testing is covered?
Means it tells me 80% of the gui is tested and it shows me the rest which I can still test the good old way ;-)

Comment: Are there any UI tests you can do without automation tools ? Well as testing code-behind in windows forms is hard I guess NO ? Can someone share his experience with that matter please.

Comment: @msfanboy: you can unit test a lot of the code behind in WinForms if you make sure your business logic is decoupled from the UI manipulation (ie. MVC or MVVM).

Comment: so when should I use tools like automatedQA or do unit tests for myself with my own code? When do I prefer which approach?

Comment: @adrianbanks well we use MVP Pattern but sometimes not the pure way ;-) so I guess we will have problems unit testing the code-behind

Comment: As a rule of thumb, write unit tests that go behind the GUI as much as possible; they are much easier to automate and integrate with your build process, so you will end up running them more frequently.  Then you can use a UI automation tool such as AutomatedQA to fill in the gaps and run tests that are specific to the GUI; you may well be surpised how much you can cover with the unit tests.