# WindowLicker for .NET's WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gui-test-framework

Is there anything like [WindowLicker](http://code.google.com/p/windowlicker/)(a GUI test framework) but for .NET's WinForms?

Thanks

Comment: For those who didn't bother to look at the link: He is asking for a GUI test framework.

Comment: There are lots of similar questions already that you could look at, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450806/looking-for-some-good-gui-testing-frameworks-gui-automation-test-tools-for-window and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465455/testing-automation-tools-for-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213/can-you-recommend-low-cost-automated-testing-tools-for-a-net-winforms-applicatio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194887/automated-windows-ui-testing-approach

Comment: In fact I think it's an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450806/looking-for-some-good-gui-testing-frameworks-gui-automation-test-tools-for-window which is also asking for a GUI test automation framework for WinForms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Looks just like what I was looking for. But seems the last alpha is from 2006 !

Answer (score 4):

[White](http://white.codeplex.com/) is open source and developed by the guys from ThoughtWorks, pretty good the last time I checked.

If you don't care going commercial, TestComplete from automated QA can also be a good quality/price combination. We use it in our process and gets the job done so far.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can create GUI tests with Visual Studio 2010 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can automate a test a windows process from outside the process with .net 3.0's UI Automation: http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/06/introduction-to-ui-automation-with.html

It's similar in idea to [AutoHotKey](http://www.AutoHotKey.com) which I've also used for UI testing.